# Are longest events always stacked first vertically in Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and It seems like longest events are always stacked first. Is there a way to tweak this behaviour?

Comment: There aren't any options to do this, so I think it would take some modification of the plugin itself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure out how to change this but any hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a requested issue:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=364

hopefully will get to it at some point